# Return false on jQuery post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm passing a value for an insert and adding + 1 but I thought success: function(html) would not execute if my check returned that the value already existed (echo its already there in the PHP). Even if the insert does not happen, success gets executed, why is that ?

How do I get the AJAX to execute only if the insert happens (If the value doesn't yet exist)

JQUERY  AJAX

```javascript
$(function addThumbs() {
    $('.vote-up').bind('click', function() {
        // 'this' is a DOM element
        // wrap 'this' in a jQuery object
        var img = $(this);
        // now we have the full jQuery API at our disposal
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        var thumbsElem = img.closest(".thumbs");
        var review_id = thumbsElem.find("#review_id").val();
        var score = thumbsElem.find("#pluses").html();
        var scoreupdated = parseInt(score) + 1;
        if (review_id == 1) 
        { alert('...'); }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax-thumbsup.php",
                data:{  
                    "user_id" : user_id, 
                    "review_id" : review_id       //we are passing the name value in URL
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    img.attr('src', 'img/upgreen.png');
                    thumbsElem.find("#pluses").html(scoreupdated);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP

```php
<?php
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
$review_id = $_REQUEST['review_id'];

require('inc/db.php');
$plusesfind = "SELECT * FROM reviews_likes WHERE review_id = :review_id AND user_id = :user_id";
$plusesfind = $conn->prepare($plusesfind);
$plusesfind->execute(array(':review_id' => $review_id, ':user_id' => $user_id));
if(!$pluses = $plusesfind->fetch()) :
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    mysql_select_db("mytvbox", $con);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO reviews_likes (review_id, user_id, plus, minus) VALUES (' . $review_id .', ' . $user_id .', ' . 1 .' , ' . 0 .')';

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{
        echo "success";
    }

    mysql_close($con);
else :

    echo "it's already there";
endif ;
?>
```

Comment: How should JavaScript know if the insert was successful or not? It doesn't understand English.

Comment: that's unfortunate... But seriously I know what you mean, I figured that out as I was writing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (*as you are echoing `success` on successful query*) -

```
success: function(html){
    if(html === "success"){
       img.attr('src', 'img/upgreen.png');
       thumbsElem.find("#pluses").html(scoreupdated);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning `success` in case of a successfull insert you can check for that value in the success callback

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-thumbsup.php",
    data:{  
        "user_id" : user_id, 
        "review_id" : review_id       //we are passing the name value in URL
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        if(html == 'success'){
            img.attr('src', 'img/upgreen.png');
            thumbsElem.find("#pluses").html(scoreupdated);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
success: function(result){
    if(result=== "success"){
       img.attr('src', 'img/upgreen.png');
       thumbsElem.find("#pluses").html(scoreupdated);
    }
}
```